# Tool to time shift a PCAP file?

Tags: networking

Does anyone know of a tool that will take a PCAP file as input and output the same file with modified timestamps?

For example, say I have a PCAP file whose time range is March 1st, 2009 1:00pm to 2:00pm and I want to change the times so the file contains the time range March 31st, 2009 1:00pm to 2:00pm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the -t option of [editcap](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html).

Comment: *Comment from [Yair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5395145/yair):* This does not really help since the -t option of editcap will require you to know how many seconds you want to add. Meaning, if your file is a week old or so, you will need to calculate how many seconds passed since its original date till, let say, 5 minutes ago.